# Tkinter Combobox dynamically set values

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm attempting to set the options of a Tkinter Combobox dynamically. My code *almost* works, and I'm not sure why.

The code is designed to allow typing a string into an Entry box. It then searches through a list for any items that contain that string. So for example, if you type

> Mi

into the entry box the list becomes

> ['Mickey', 'Minnie']

All this works as expected.

The Combobox `[values]` attribute is supposed to update whenever `<FocusIn>` is triggered using a function. This does indeed happen, but only after I click on the Combobox twice. I'm not sure why clicking on it the first time doesn't trigger the `<FocusIn>` binding. Is this the wrong binding? Is there something about my lambda function that isn't quite right? Would love some help!

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

init_list = ['Mickey', 'Minnie', 'Donald', 'Pluto', 'Goofy']

def db_values():
    i = inp_var.get()
    db_list = [x for x in init_list if i in x]
    print(db_list)
    return db_list

def db_refresh(event):
    db['values'] = db_values()

root = Tk()
title_label = Label(root, text="Partial string example")
title_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

inp_var = StringVar()
input_box = Entry(root, textvariable=inp_var)
input_box.grid(column=0, row=1)

name_selected = StringVar()
db = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=name_selected)
db['values'] = db_values()
db.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda event: db_refresh(event))
db.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=EW, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your issue. But your code doesn't have a main entry point `if __name__ == "__main__":`, this could lead to unexpected behavior.  Read [Is this bad programming practice in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454065/is-this-bad-programming-practice-in-tkinter)

Comment: @stovfi Click on the drop arrow. The first time it won't bring up the list properly.

Comment: Change to `db.bind('<Enter>', db_refresh)`, called on moving the pointer on the `Combobox` before you click the drop arrow. Relevant [how-to-bind-keypress-event-for-combobox-drop-out-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53848622/how-to-bind-keypress-event-for-combobox-drop-out-menu-in-tkinter-python-3-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def db_values():
    i = inp_var.get()
    db_list = [x for x in init_list if i in x]
    print(db_list)
    db['values'] = db_values()
```

Only this small Change is requires. list value must be assigned in the function itself.