# Is it possible to bind events to an open tkinter Combobox?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have been trying to make this work for a while now, but to no avail. I'm trying to implement a simple key bind to a tkinter combobox widget for the user to be able to navigate the list of values alphabetically, but it never works when the Combobox is open, only when it's closed. Any help is appreciated!

Here's a snippet:

```
def navigateKey(event):
   key=event.char.upper()
   from string import ascii_uppercase as letters
   if key in letters:
      for index, curr in enumerate(curcodes):
         if curr[0] == key:
            trxcurrmenu.current(index)
            break
trxcurrmenu.bind("<Key>", navigateKey)
```

EDIT: as requested, here's an illustration of the issue:
[event binding issue example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8pLl.png)

Comment: Could you show a minimal example?

Comment: Hi, just edited the OP and added a screenshot of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it is possible as the popup menu is another widget inside `Combobox` which includes an `Entry`, a popup menu and the arrow button.  The binding is on the `Entry`, not on the popup menu.

Comment: Bummer, but thanks for the answer. I guess tinkering with the module itself would be the only solution then?

Comment: If you want to access the internal widgets, [how-to-bind-keypress-event-for-combobox-drop-out-menu-in-tkinter-python-3-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53848622/how-to-bind-keypress-event-for-combobox-drop-out-menu-in-tkinter-python-3-7) may help.

Comment: Thanks will take a look!